# AdColony Video Ad Crash: Failed to create remote render context

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, xcode5, adcolony

```
Reason: Failed to create remote render context;
...
-[ADCRootViewController initWithNibName:bundle:]  'ADCRootViewController.m' line 54
-[ADCCore init]  'ADCCore.m' line 81
__25+[ADCCore sharedInstance]_block_invoke_2  'ADCCore.m' line 345
__25+[ADCCore sharedInstance]_block_invoke  'ADCCore.m' line 345
unknown undefine
+[ADCCore sharedInstance]  'once.h' line 68
+[AdColony configureWithAppID:zoneIDs:delegate:logging:]  'AdColony.m' line 308
...
```

I attached a portion of my symbolicated crash log. The crash points to AdColony's class. Does anyone know why this happen? How can I prevent AdColony from making my app crash? Thanks.

Comment: did It solved? I meet same problem.

Comment: Sorry. we weren't able to solve this issue. The best we could do at the time was to update to latest AdColony.